# Why does my series value's label goes hover the axis max value?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using reporting services 2016 and I have one question.

Sometimes, my series value is to high and the label goes above my axis. Sometimes it's ok, but sometimes the value goes hover a text and it's pretty annoying!

[image: Padding]

I tried to see if there's a way to set-up either a top margin value or to change the axis value and make it 1.5 times bigger per example.

But I didn't find any way to change the margin top or to change my axis value.

I tried this for this axis solution : I tried to get the max value of my value and multiple it by 2.

```
=Max(sum(Fields!Amount_Qty.Value),"DS_values")*2
```

But it didn't work. The value is still the same.

Any idea?

**Edit**
Here is what I have :

[image]

The values' label goes actually hover my X axis label.

So what I want is to make the Y axis max value, 2 times bigger without changing my dataset.

[image]

Here per example the max value would be 8000k and note 4000k.

So I right clicked on the Y axis -> Vertcal Axis Properties and I did this :

[image]

Inside the `Minimum` the expression is this :

```
=Min(sum(Fields!Amount_Qty.Value),"Chart10_CategoryGroup")*-2
```

My Dataset works like this : I have 3 values

1. Amount_QTY
2. Revenues
3. Amount_order

All of them are a sum. Expect for the Amount_QTY which is a sum *-1 (I want negative values for this).

And here is my Category groups :

[image]

And their properties :

[image]

**EDIT : Result**

The result :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revised after update from OP**

OP Stated that actual values are positive but shown as negative in the chart.

If you want to move the whole thing up then you need to set the Y-Axis MIN value to be

```
=MAX(sum(Fields!Amount_Qty.Value),"myCategoryGroupName")* -2
```

Because your database values are positive, you want the `MAX` value, then just invert and double it by multiplying by -2. Also, assuming that there is more than 1 value per X-Axis point and you are summing the values in your chart, your scope needs to be the name of the category group. In the chart, right-click the category group entry and choose "Category Group Properties" and you will see the name you need.

**Working example.**
I created a small dataset with the following query

```
declare @t table (x int, myValue int)
insert into @t values 
(1,3000), (2,3200), (3,3400), (4,3600), (5,3800), (6,4000), (7,4200)
, (8,4400), (8,4000), (9,4600), (10,4800)
SELECT * FROM @t
```

These all have only a single value for each X category except for when X=8. There are two values here just to show the aggregation calculations are working.

Using the above as my dataset query, I added a simple column chart.

[image]

The expression for the Chart Data Values just multiplies the `myValue` column by -1 and is

```
=Sum(Fields!myValue.Value) *-1
```

I then got the Category Group name from the Category Group Properties, in this case it's `Chart1_CategoryGroup`

[image]

Finally, I set the Vertical Axis Minimum expression to be

```
=MAX(SUM(Fields!myValue.Value, "Chart1_CategoryGroup"))*-2
```

This expression sums by category group first, then takes the max of those results and then multiplies that number by -2 to set the lowest Y-Axis value to, in this case, -16800. This comes from the two values where x=8 (4400 and 4000) = 8400; * -2 = -16800

[image]

If I run the report now I get this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I forgot to say 2 things, the first is my values aren't negative in the dataset. I do a `sum(Fields!Amount_Qty.Value)*-1` on the values. I right clicked on the Y axis and goes to Axis options and then in the minimum values I wrote your code but the value doesn't change. My Category group name is `Chart10_CategoryGroup`. All I want to do is to add a padding between my X axis and the chart's values.

Comment: If your values are positive, then you would need to multiply by `* -2` as your Y-Axis Min value still needs to be negative. I've created a simply report that does this and it works as expected. If this does not help, edit your question and show screenshots of the relevant chart properties and a sample of data to test with.

Comment: I edited my question if you wanna check !

Comment: I'll edit my answer a little later (too much work on at the moment) and show you what I did. My sample appears to do what you are trying do to.

Comment: I've edited the answer with a revised expression (gone back to MAX as your values are +ve). Hopefully this works now, if not I will post screen shots of sample report later this evening.

Comment: Can you post screen shots please ?

Comment: Ok It worked thank you! But I have 2 more problems now, the first one is : the 0 value isn't aligned with the horizontal line. And the second one is : how can I have round number ? Like I had before (2000k and 4000k).

Comment: You'll need to ask new questions to avoid the subject being different from the answers. Mark this answer as accepted 9as it has now been correctly answered) then ask new questions for each of these new issues.